# Couchbase DefaultOrphanResponseReporter Orphan responses observed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I have a SpringBoot 2 app that uses using Spring Data Couchbase.
I have this message on the logs every minute

```
2019-11-12 13:48:48,924 WARN  :  gid: trace= span= [cb-orphan-1] c.c.c.c.t.DefaultOrphanResponseReporter Orphan responses observed: [{"top":[{"r":"10.120.93.220:8092","s":"view","c":"5BE128F6F96A4D28/FFFFFFFFDA2C8C52","l":"10.125.216.233:49893"}],"service":"view","count":1}]
```

That is from the new Response Time Observability feature underlying the Java SDK. 
It would seem to indicate that you have view requests which are timing out, but eventually received later, but I have no views defined in Couchbase DB

I would like to know if it is possible to disable OrphanResponseLogReporter via YML file config in a SpringBoot app. , setting the logIntervalNanos to 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unfortunately, you cannot do it. Only a subset of Couchbase's configuration properties is supported in the application.yml, namely the ones present in the [CouchbaseProperties.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/couchbase/CouchbaseProperties.java) class.

You could although use an environment variable: `com.couchbase.orphanResponseReportingEnabled=false`. It is independent of Spring, it's read directly by Couchbase SDK.

**Edit:**

As a workaround, you can set logging level in the application.yml:
`logging.level.com.couchbase.client.core.tracing.DefaultOrphanResponseReporter: ERROR`